# WiFi repeaters that duplicate the broadcast wireless signal?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, repeater

I live in a house with many plaster walls and want a device that will duplicate the wireless signal sent out of an AP/router to act in tandem with other AP/routers on the same network.  From the client perspective, it should be physically equivalent to placing multiple antennas throughout a space.  It would by definition use the same SSID and somehow manage the multiple received signals.

I can't seem to find such a device or software feature.  Does one exist?  There seems to be much ambiguity about the terms "repeater," "range extender," etc.  Is there a well-established name for this feature?

Alternately, I don't mind if there are "roaming" handoffs between access points, but they must be forced by the APs rather than waiting for the client to realize that the connection is poor.

Comment: There is no such feature in a WiFi device because it is not a WiFi feature. Not only does it not exist, it's practically impossible. If you want a distributed antenna system, buy a distributed antenna system.

Comment: It's definitely not impossible; I wasn't asking if a WiFi standard existed to support it because it's not necessary.  I know that there are plenty of proprietary protocols to support roaming by booting clients off APs when signal strength is weak.  I'm asking only if a product or feature exists that accomplishes this.

Comment: It definitely **is** impossible. Any such device would simply cause a feedback loop with itself. It'd boot everyone off all the time.

Comment: If standard roaming isn't suitable for you and you absolutely must have have AP-controlled roaming you should try virtualized WLAN solutions like Meru or Extricom. By broadcasting a duplicated signal (NOT duplicating a broadcast signal) it does what you want without breaking the RF spectrum.

Comment: The OP makes it sound like homeplugs would be an ideal solution. If they arent, you need a managed solution End of.

Comment: "_Alternately, I don't mind if there are "roaming" handoffs between access points, but they must be forced by the APs rather than waiting for the client to realize that the connection is poor._ With Wi-Fi, roaming is completely up to the client. The WAP cannot force roaming on a client.

Answer (score 0):

To increase your Wi-Fi coverage, you could add a wireless repeater ("range extender"). 
You should place the repeater at the outer range of your existing router’s coverage where it still receives good signals. This would repeat the network signals between the existing router and any connected wifi equipment.

The problem with this approach is that it significantly reduces the network speeds for those connecting via the repeater.

A better alternative would be to use so called MoCA adapters (Multimedia Over Coax) that allow you to use existing copper cables in the house to bridge your network to the electrical/cable lines in various configurations.

Comment: I am familiar with typical wireless and wired range extenders. These force clients to monitor the connection and switch APs, which has proven very unreliable.  My question is not about those.

Comment: Ok. I misunderstood the question then.